# Map a hash key based on value in another hash of array in Perl

Tags: perl, hashmap

Below Hashes contain some node data.

`%Main_hash`, `%SC_Hash` and `%Cell_Hash`.

I want to print Equipment(`S_<count>`) and its respective Cells(`C_<count>`) from these hashes using hash map.

Here is my script:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %Main_hash = ( 'Network=Test,Equipment=2' => [ 'A', 'B' ],
                  'Network=Test,Equipment=3' => [ 'X', 'Y' ],
                  'Network=Test,Equipment=1' => [ 'D', 'F' ]);
my %SC_Hash = (   'Network=Test,Carrier=3' => 'Network=Test,Equipment=3',
                  'Network=Test,Carrier=1' => 'Network=Test,Equipment=1',
                  'Network=Test,Carrier=2' => 'Network=Test,Equipment=2');
my %Cell_Hash = ( 'Network=Test,Cell=34' => [ 'Network=Test,Carrier=1' ],
                  'Network=Test,Cell=31' => [ 'Network=Test,Carrier=1' ],
                  'Network=Test,Cell=37' => [ 'Network=Test,Carrier=3' ]);

my $count = 0;

foreach my $equipment (sort keys %Main_hash){
    $count++;
    print "S_$count=$equipment\n";
    my ($k) = grep { $SC_Hash{$_} =~ /$equipment/ } keys %SC_Hash;
    print "C_$count=$k\n";
}
```

Here I am getting output like this (**current output**):

```
S_1=Network=Test,Equipment=1
C_1=Network=Test,Carrier=1
S_2=Network=Test,Equipment=2
C_2=Network=Test,Carrier=2
S_3=Network=Test,Equipment=3
C_3=Network=Test,Carrier=3
```

But I am **expecting output** like below:

```
S_1=Network=Test,Equipment=1
C_1=Network=Test,Cell=31###Network=Test,Cell=34
S_2=Network=Test,Equipment=2
C_2=NA
S_3=Network=Test,Equipment=3
C_3=Network=Test,Cell=37
```

If you see the current output, for `C_1` its printing `Network=Test,Carrier=1`. But it should look for `Network=Test,Carrier=1`'s key in `%Cell_Hash` and print its key(i.e. `Network=Test,Cell=31` and `Network=Test,Cell=34`).

1. If a particular Carrier matches with multiple keys of `%Cell_Hash` then it should be printed with delimited by `###` as shown in `C_1`'s value in the expected output.
2. And for `C_2`, value is `Network=Test,Carrier=2`, which doesn't exists in `%Cell_Hash`'s any of the array values. This leads there is no key exists for `Network=Test,Carrier=2` in `%Cell_Hash` hash. It should print value as `NA` in `C_2` as shown in the expected output.

Comment: This is the same as your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64433535/589924). You need cells grouped by equipment, so create that

Comment: @ikegami yes, but there relation is straight forward, here I have 2 more hashes to get the relation.

Comment: Ah, so you've tried? Where's what you tried? /// But no, it's not really any more complicated. In fact, it's virtually identical. You really just need cells grouped by carrier, which is exactly what the earlier question answered. You can already easily lookup the equipment of a carrier.

Comment: @ikegami I could able to map equipment with carrier shown in _current output_. but from carrier to cell seems to be complicated for me since its in the hash of arrays :|

Comment: It was an AoH in you earlier question too.

Comment: @ikegami Sorted it out. Your earlier answer helped much. thank you again. We can close this question.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired output you can try change this line:

```
print "C_$count=$k\n";
```

to

```
my $sc_value = get_scvalue( $k );
say "C_$count=$sc_value";
```

where `get_scvalue()` can be defined like:

```
sub get_scvalue {
    my ($k) = @_;
    my @values;
    for my $ch_key (keys %Cell_Hash) {
        my $v = $Cell_Hash{$ch_key};
        die "Not array ref!" if ref $v ne "ARRAY";
        die "Unexpected array len!" if scalar @$v != 1;
        my $vstr = $v->[0];
        if ( $vstr eq $k ) {
            push @values, $ch_key;
        }
    }
    @values = "NA" if @values == 0;
    my $value = join "###", @values;
    return $value;
}
```