# Search whether AoH value exists in same Hash

Tags: perl

I have hash which contains some data.

I want my final `%hash` to be printed like this:

```
'UGroup=1' => [ 'C72', 'C73', 'C71' ]
```

Here is my script:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = (
            'C72'      => [ 'S=2-1' ],
            'C73'      => [ 'S=3-1' ],
            'C71'      => [ 'S=91-1'],
            'UGroup=1' => [ 'S=1-1',
                            'S=2-1',
                            'S=3-1',
                            'S=91-1'],
        );

print Dumper(\%h);

foreach my $C (sort keys %h) {
    next unless $C =~ /UGroup/;
    for my $f (@{$h{$C}}){
        print "\tf:$f\n";
        #This is not correct, but wanted to do something like this.
        push @{$hash{$C}}, $f if(exists $h{$f}); 
    }
}

print Dumper(\%hash);
```

Here in example input hash I need to check if `S=91-1` has any key? If yes then associate that key to value for `%hash` with its original key.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why is the output `'UGroup=1' => [ 'C71' ]` rather than `C71 => [ 'UGroup=1' ]`?

Comment: @ikegami - this is different requirement I have actually. I need in this way my hash to be created. Once I create the hash, I need to do have `###` separated for more than one C<NUM>. Hence its basically UGroup to Cell relation now.

Comment: I have no idea what your comment is say, then. Doesn't appear to be answering the my comment at all.

Comment: ok, I see your code doesn't do what you say at all. You're not interested in `S=91-1`; you're interested in the values associated with the keys containing `UGroup`

Comment: @ikegami Extremely sorry for the confusion. I already have hash `%h`. The thing is I need to exctract only `UGroup`'s from them with their respective Cells. To get the cells the relation is Cell vs Sector(`S`).

Comment: Wouldn't the result be `'UGroup=1' => [ 'C71', 'C72', 'C73' ]`?

Comment: @ikegami you're absolutely correct. I'll make a modification to the question. I missed it because I was looking into different input hash in my test script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't name the things, so

- `S=91-1` shall be a snake,
- `C71` shall be a cow, and
- `UGroup=1` shall be a group.

Start by [building this hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64433869/589924):

```perl
my %cows_by_snake = (
   'S=91-1' => [ 'C71' ],
   'S=2-1'  => [ 'C72' ],
   'S=3-1'  => [ 'C73' ],
);
```

Just ignore the keys that of `%h` that are groups when you do so.

Once you built a hash, it's simply a question of doing the following:

1. Create an empty result hash.
2. For each group,

   1. Create an empty collection of cows.
   2. For each snake associated the the group,

      1. Add the cows associated with the snake to the collection.
   3. Eliminate the duplicates in the collection of cows.
   4. Add the group and the associated cows to the result hash.

---

```perl
my @groups;
my @cows;
for my $cow_or_group (keys(%h)) {
   if ($cow_or_group =~ /^UGroup=/) {
      push @groups, $cow_or_group;
   } else {
      push @cows, $cow_or_group;
   }
}

my %cows_by_snake;
for my $cow (@cows) {
   for my $snake (@{ $h{$cow} }) {
      push @{ $cows_by_snake{$snake} }, $cow;
   }
}

my %results;
for my $group (@groups) {
   my %group_cows;
   for my $snake (@{ $h{$group} }) {
      for my $cow (@{ $cows_by_snake{$snake} }) {
         ++$group_cows{$cow};
      }
   }

   $results{$group} = [ sort keys %group_cows ];
}
```

Comment: I could able to build `cows_by_snake` hash. If I loop through this hash, key is snake. How to replace it with group?

Comment: What? . . . . . .

Comment: I have `%cows_by_snake` hash with data which you mentioned above. If I do `foreach` of `%cows_by_snake`, key is snake. How do I get group in that place.

Comment: How do you get what group? Don't actually answer that. Comments aren't the place for new, unrelated questions.

Comment: I mean instead of `S=91-1` how I can print `UGroup=1`. Since the hash `%cows_by_snake` contains `S=91-1` as a key.

Comment: Again, that doesn't appear to have anything to do with my answer (which doesn't print anything) or the question.

Comment: I have made the changes to the script. Please let me know if this is correct. I could able to get the result as expected. Here it is: https://privatebin.net/?500f326b38ba0bcf#u75BQ3o9uZV1Dvh7hEKJQN5yfHg7ySaeVoAPWX6w6FK

Comment: If two cows can have the same snake, you'll get duplicates. (You really gotta use better var names. Your code is HORRIBLE because of your var name choices.)

Comment: I'll rewrite the code with better var names. Logically do you think it's right?

Comment: Fixed. I have manage to eliminate the duplicates too. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Solution added.

Comment: My script produces result hash like this: `$VAR1 = { 'UGroup=1' => [ 'C72', 'C73', 'C71' ] };`. Yours is with UGroup and Sector relation.

Comment: Woops, fixed. Tested.